# Making a copy of a list

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a "target", a copy of "grid." I don't see why this code does not work.

```
grid = [[randint(0, 1), randint(0, 1), randint(0, 1)],
        [randint(0, 1), randint(0, 1), randint(0, 1)],
        [randint(0, 1), randint(0, 1), randint(0, 1)]]

target = [[0, 0, 0]] * 3
for x in range(3):
    for y in range(3):
        target[x][y] = grid[x][y]

print target
print grid
```

Here's a result:

```
[[0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0]]
[[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0]]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This part:

```
target = [[0, 0, 0]] * 3
```

Creates a list with the same list repeated 3 times. So changes to one item actually reflects in all (they are the same object). What you want is to create a list three times:

```
target = [[0, 0, 0] for _ in range(3)]
```

You should only use the star operator on list (or list multiplication) with [immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) objects (if at all), which do not have this problem since you can't change their states.

Don't forget you can use (`x[:]` is used to create a **shallow** copy of a list named `x`, just like `list(x)`):

```
grid = [x[:] for x in target]
```

Or even more generally with [`copy.deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy):

```
from copy import deepcopy
grid = deepcopy(target)
```

Comment: Wow. For a novice like me that's very subtle thing to keep in mind. Thanks!

Comment: @IanTan You may be unfamiliar with the `x[:]` syntax then, it's just a method to create a copy of the list -- [here are alternative syntaxes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list-in-python)

Comment: Thanks. This is very convenient.

Comment: The other way to copy a list is x = list (yourlist)

Comment: @FredMitchell this creates a shallow copy so you're still concerned with what you're copying. `deepcopy` iteratively deep-copies all items in more complex nested types such as `dict`s or `list`s